# Не создается объект после нажатия кнопки. POST запрос отправляется

Tags: python, django

Подскажите пожалуйста.. Сделал функцию создания объекта во views.py, настроил шаблон, но увы не работает. POST запрос происходит, поля в которых надо выбирать вариант сбрасываются, но объект не создается.

```
def todo_create(request):
    todos = Todo.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    form = TodoCreateForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TodoCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    context = {'form':form, 'todos':todos, 'categories':categories}
    return render(request, 'todolist/todo_create.html', context)
```

В урлах проблем быть не должно, могу скинуть html кнопки, но думаю это ничего не даст. Форма в шаблоне имеет метод POST

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
def todo_create(request):
    todos = Todo.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TodoCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
        context = {'form':form, 'todos':todos, 'categories':categories}
        return render(request, 'todolist/todo_create.html', context)
    form = TodoCreateForm()
    context = {'form':form, 'todos':todos, 'categories':categories}
    return render(request, 'todolist/todo_create.html', context)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Попробую сделать

Comment: Все равно не работает.